# why use nifi putHDFS command?

Tags: apache-nifi

since "load local"  command can load data from local file system to hive table, I'm unsure why most of people would like to putHFDS + replaceText + HiveQL. isn't better to use "replaceText + HiveQL" only instead of adding 1 more processor:putHDFS in workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Many times NiFi will be running on a server outside the Hadoop cluster where the Hadoop client doesn't exist, so PutHDFS is transferring the data from that server to HDFS, and then ReplaceText + PutHiveQL is a way to create a Hive external table on top of the data that just landed in HDFS.